# Full Calendar refetched events when react set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am using full calendars api as follows for fetching my events-

```
<FullCalendar
                ref={calendarRef}
                plugins={[listPlugin, bootstrap5Plugin]}
                initialView='listMonth'
                themeSystem='bootstrap5'
                validRange={{ "start": currentDateTime }}
                headerToolbar={{
                    start: 'listMonth prev next',
                    center: 'title',
                    end: 'Schedule',
                }}
                views={
                    {listMonth: { buttonText: 'Month' }}
                }
                eventOrder={'end'}
                customButtons={{
                    Schedule: {
                        text: 'Schedule Meeting',
                        click: function () {
                            handleCustomButtonClick();
                        }
                    }
                }}
                events={function (info, successCallback, failureCallback){
                    var startDateTime = info.start;
                    var endDateTime = info.end;

                    startDateTime.setMilliseconds(0);
                    endDateTime.setMilliseconds(0);

                    startDateTime = startDateTime.toISOString();
                    endDateTime = endDateTime.toISOString();
                    
                    startDateTime = startDateTime.substring(0, startDateTime.length - 5) + 'Z';
                    endDateTime = endDateTime.substring(0, endDateTime.length - 5) + 'Z';

                    const url = `http://localhost:8080/api/meeting/abhyasi/${props.profile.googleId}/${startDateTime}/${endDateTime}`; // Use backticks for template literals
                    const headers = new Headers();
                
                    // Add headers to the headers object
                    headers.append('X-API-KEY', ",PRGojtX9`c4e24219-fb95-;'.4ed8392hfds';");
                
                    const requestOptions = {
                        method: 'GET',
                        headers: headers
                    };
                
                    const response = fetch(url, requestOptions)
                    fetch(url, requestOptions)
                    .then(response => {
                        // check if the response is a 404
                        if (response.status === 404) {
                            // if it is, then throw an error
                            failureCallback();
                        }
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(data => {
                        // Handle the JSON data here
                        console.log(data);
                        // map to events object
                        var meeting_events = data.map((meeting) => {
                            return {
                                title: meeting.meetingAgenda,
                                start: meeting.startDateTime,
                                end: meeting.endDateTime,
                                extendedProps: {
                                    startUrl: meeting.meetingStartUrl,
                                    joinUrl: meeting.meetingJoinUrl,
                                    meetingId: meeting.zoomMeetingId,
                                    meetingPassword: meeting.meetingPassword
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        successCallback(meeting_events);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        // Handle any errors that occurred during the fetch
                        failureCallback(error);
                    });
                }}
                eventDidMount={
                    function(info) {

                        let start = info.event.start.toISOString();
                        let end = info.event.end.toISOString();
                        let current = new Date().toISOString();

                        if(current < end) {
                            var button = document.createElement('button');
                            button.innerHTML = 'Delete Meeting';
                            button.className = 'btn btn-primary btn-sm';
                            button.classList.add('float-end');
                            button.style.marginLeft = '10px';
                            button.style.borderRadius = '5px';
                            button.style.backgroundColor = '#dc3545';
                            button.style.borderColor = '#dc3545';
                            button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                deleteMeeting(info.event);
                            }
                            );

                            info.el.querySelector('.fc-list-event-title').appendChild(button);
                        }

                        if(start <= current && end >= current) {
                            var button = document.createElement('button');
                            button.innerHTML = 'Start';
                            button.className = 'btn btn-primary btn-sm';
                            button.classList.add('float-end');
                            button.style.marginLeft = '10px';
                            button.style.borderRadius = '5px';
                            button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                window.open(info.event.extendedProps.startUrl);
                            }
                            );
    
                            info.el.querySelector('.fc-list-event-title').appendChild(button);
                        }

                        if(end > current) {
                            var button = document.createElement('button');
                            button.innerHTML = 'Info';
                            button.className = 'btn btn-primary btn-sm';
                            button.style.marginLeft = '10px';
                            button.style.borderRadius = '5px';
                            button.classList.add('float-end');
                            button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                setEvent(info.event);
                                presentInfoModal();
                            }
                            );

                            // add button to the extreme right
                            info.el.querySelector('.fc-list-event-title').appendChild(button);
                        }

                    }
                }
            />
            <InfoMeetingModal />
            <Modal show={showModal}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton onClick={closeModal}>
                <Modal.Title>Schedule Meeting</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body >
                <Form >
                    <Form.Group controlId="datePicker">
                    <Form.Label className='form-label'>Date</Form.Label>
                    <DatePicker
                        selected={selectedDate}
                        onChange={handleDateChange}
                        dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
                        className='form-date-picker'
                    />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group controlId="startTimePicker">
                    <Form.Label className='form-label'>Start Time</Form.Label>
                    <DatePicker
                        selected={selectedStartTime}
                        onChange={handleStartTimeChange}
                        showTimeSelect
                        showTimeSelectOnly
                        timeIntervals={15}
                        timeCaption="Start Time"
                        dateFormat="h:mm aa"
                        className='form-date-picker'
                    />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group controlId="endTimePicker">
                    <Form.Label className='form-label'>End Time</Form.Label>
                    <DatePicker
                        selected={selectedEndTime}
                        onChange={handleEndTimeChange}
                        showTimeSelect
                        showTimeSelectOnly
                        timeIntervals={15}
                        timeCaption="End Time"
                        dateFormat="h:mm aa"
                        className='form-date-picker'
                    />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group controlId="meetingDescription">
                    <Form.Label>Meeting Description</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter meeting description"
                        value={meetingDescription}
                        onChange={handleDescriptionChange}
                        className='form-text-box'
                    />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              
                <Button variant="danger" onClick={closeModal}>
                Close
                </Button>
                <Button variant="dark" onClick={createMeeting}>
                Save
                </Button>
                <Spinner id='spinner' animation="border" role="status" hidden={!loading}> </Spinner>
            </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );

    function InfoMeetingModal() {
        return (
            <Modal show={showInfoModal}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton onClick={closeInfoModal}>
                    <Modal.Title>Meeting Details</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    {
                        console.log(selectedEvent)
                    }
                        <div>
                        <p>Meeting ID: {selectedEvent.extendedProps.meetingId}</p>
                        <p>Meeting Password: {selectedEvent.extendedProps.meetingPassword}</p>
                        <p>Start Time: {
                            // format time to current zone in hh:mm am/pm format
                            new Date(selectedEvent.start).toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true })
                        } {currentZone}
                        </p>
                        <p>End Time: {
                            // format time to current zone in hh:mm am/pm format
                            new Date(selectedEvent.end).toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true })
                        } {currentZone}</p>
                        <p>Meeting Description: {selectedEvent.title}</p>
                        <div>Join Url: {selectedEvent.extendedProps.joinUrl}</div>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
```

The problem is when I am entering dates or times in the modals below, (by setting state) the events are refetched.

The events function just fetches the data source from my backend server. I saw a post that used useMemo to solve this issue. However I am quite new to react and web dev, I was not able to understand it ([Fullcalendar re-fetch events after change in React state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70839624/fullcalendar-re-fetch-events-after-change-in-react-state?rq=3))

How can I fix this?

Comment: The link you provided says that every time render happens a new instance of `function` is created passed in event={function} . So what he did is me moved the function code inside a new function `memoizedEventsFn` and memoized `memoizedEventsFn ` with `useMemo()` hook.
Memoization is the process that if result of a function with some arguments was earlier already calculated then we directly return the result instead of re-calculating the whole function.  Maybe you can also try to move your code given in event={….} to a function and then try memoize the function.

Answer (score 0):

From your information, I understand that the problem lies in the function passed to the `events` prop. Now, you have passed the info, and from that, you are taking the start and end date, so every time that changes, the function will re-created, and all the events will be fetched again.

You can move the function from the `events` prop inside a `useMemo` hook with info as a dependency for the solution.